# WPF - Image hide userControl : how access the userControl contextMenu?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, contextmenu, hidden

In my application I have a userControl and some images on a canvas.

The userControl can be moved and has a contextMenu.

Everything work well, but sometimes an image has a zIndex higher than the zIndex of the userControl (I can see the userControl because the image has an reduced opacity). As the control is hidden by the image, I no longer have access to the contextMenu. It's logical, the right click event is linked to the image and not the userControl.

There is the possibility to disable the events on the image, and activate the events on the userControl ?
Or may be it is possible to translate the event on the image to the userControl ?

Thanks you for your help

Damien

PS : I hope my english is not too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the image.

Comment: The image is added in codebehind. I have added "image.IsHitTestVisible = false;" but I can not open the context menu.

Comment: I had updated the wrong image. With the correct code, your suggestion is correct. Many thanks